# RSpec error: Cannot connect to Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, redis

I'm trying to set up RSpec tests around a Ruby Rails application I just wrote. The application is an add-on to a much larger project, and I'm not very familiar with the environment yet. I've also never used RSpec before, so chances are this is a basic problem.

To start out, I wrote a few basic tests that should not fail:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require '../../../lib/release_notes/release_notes_generator'

describe ReleaseNotesGenerator do
  before :each do
    @rng = ReleaseNotesGenerator.new()
  end

  it 'should print hello world' do
    puts "Hello world!"
  end

  describe "#new" do
    it "tests basic rspec syntax" do
      @rng.should be_an_instance_of ReleaseNotesGenerator
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I run these tests I get this error:

```
An error occurred in an after(:all) hook.
  Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)
  occurred at /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:276:in `rescue in establish_connection'
```

How does Redis factor into RSpec tests? None of my work up to this point has involved Redis at all. I did some searches, but I can't find any other mention of this error.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: Here is the complete stack trace (it's fairly long)

```
[Zonebie] Setting timezone to "Almaty"

ReleaseNotesGenerator
  should print hello world (FAILED - 1)
  #new
    tests basic rspec syntax (FAILED - 2)

An error occurred in an after(:all) hook.
  Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)
  occurred at /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:276:in `rescue in establish_connection'


Failures:

  1) ReleaseNotesGenerator should print hello world
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     Redis::CannotConnectError:
       Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:276:in `rescue in establish_connection'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:271:in `establish_connection'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:69:in `connect'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:290:in `ensure_connected'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:177:in `block in process'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:256:in `logging'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:176:in `process'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:84:in `call'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in select'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `block in synchronize'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `synchronize'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:67:in `select'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-namespace-1.2.1/lib/redis/namespace.rb:257:in `method_missing'
     # /Users/nadams/Workspace/orbit-server/spec/spec_helper.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:21:in `instance_eval'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:21:in `run'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:100:in `run'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:418:in `run_hook'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:320:in `block in run_before_all_hooks'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:96:in `block in isolate_for_before_all'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:92:in `instance_eval'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:92:in `isolate_for_before_all'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:319:in `run_before_all_hooks'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:370:in `run'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'

  2) ReleaseNotesGenerator#new tests basic rspec syntax
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     Redis::CannotConnectError:
       Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED)
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:276:in `rescue in establish_connection'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:271:in `establish_connection'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:69:in `connect'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:290:in `ensure_connected'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:177:in `block in process'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:256:in `logging'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:176:in `process'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/client.rb:84:in `call'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:69:in `block in select'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `block in synchronize'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:36:in `synchronize'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis.rb:67:in `select'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/redis-namespace-1.2.1/lib/redis/namespace.rb:257:in `method_missing'
     # /Users/nadams/Workspace/orbit-server/spec/spec_helper.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:21:in `instance_eval'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:21:in `run'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:100:in `run'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:418:in `run_hook'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:320:in `block in run_before_all_hooks'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:96:in `block in isolate_for_before_all'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:92:in `instance_eval'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:92:in `isolate_for_before_all'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:319:in `run_before_all_hooks'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:370:in `run'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
     # /Users/nadams/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@orbit/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'

Finished in 0.12005 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./release_notes_spec.rb:11 # ReleaseNotesGenerator should print hello world
rspec ./release_notes_spec.rb:16 # ReleaseNotesGenerator#new tests basic rspec syntax

Randomized with seed 11682
```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace from the error?

Comment: Do you have an instance of your Redis server running on your local machine when you run these tests? That's where it's looking. If not, you need to specify where that server is running. My team set up Capistrano tasks to deploy our app, and when we did that, we found it easiest to start up our own smaller instances of Redis on our local machines to run tests through instead of hitting the production Redis server with our tests.

Comment: What's going on at spec_helper.rb:47?

Comment: @BradRice I do have a Redis server running, but I can't seem to connect with it -- I get the same ECONNREFUSED even when I run a few simple commands like "r = Redis.new; r.ping"

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Nice catch! Thanks for sticking with this problem. There is a short reference to Redis in spec_helper:

  config.before(:all) { Resque.redis.select 1 }

I examined Resque.redis and it exists, but it refuses all connections... Still need to figure out why

Comment: Did you end up solving your issue ?

Comment: Is it bad practice to have an external server (ie redis) as a dependency for running unit tests?